# What are quantum inspired algorithms?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

I am starting to see press about quantum inspired algorithms. Are these algorithms that solve problems faster by looking at things from a quantum computing perspective?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of such algorithm?

Comment: @MartinVesely I guess he means algorithms like Tang's https://scirate.com/arxiv/1807.04271, or LeGall's https://scirate.com/arxiv/1608.01426. I have not read any of them, not even https://scirate.com/arxiv/1910.06151, or https://scirate.com/arxiv/1910.05699.

Comment: the general idea is to take ideas used to develop quantum algorithms, and realise that they can sometimes be used to device classical versions of the algorithms. On top of the references given in the comment above, [Tang's blog entry](https://ewintang.com/blog/2019/01/28/an-overview-of-quantum-inspired-sampling/) might also be of interest. I would also appreciate someone more knowledgeable of the topic pitching in though.